# Use value for build.properties in replacetoken ant task

Tags: java, ant, build

I have following replacefilter:

```
<replacefilter>
   <replacetoken><![CDATA[JDBCDataSource="xyz"]]></replacetoken> 
   <replacevalue><![CDATA[JDBCDataSource="abc"]]></replacevalue>
</replacefilter>
```

How can I pass variable from build.properties file in replacetoken and replacevalue tag such as:

```
<replacefilter>
   <replacetoken><![CDATA[JDBCDataSource="${var1}"]]></replacetoken> 
   <replacevalue><![CDATA[JDBCDataSource="${var2}"]]></replacevalue>
</replacefilter>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `expandproperties` attribute:

```
<replacefilter>
    <replacetoken expandproperties="true"><![CDATA[JDBCDataSource="${var1}"]]></replacetoken> 
    <replacevalue expandproperties="true"><![CDATA[JDBCDataSource="${var2}"]]></replacevalue>
</replacefilter>
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Although my IDE shows "replacetoken does not have attribute expandProperties", it still runs..